# Matching contents of one file with another and returning second column

Tags: bash, unix

So I have two txt files 
file1.txt

```
s
j
z
z
e
```

and file2.txt

```
s h
f a
j e
k m
z l
d p
e o
```

and what I want to do is match the first letter of file1 with the first letter of file 2 and return the second column of file 2. so for example excepted output would be

```
h
e
l
l
o
```

I'm trying to use join file1.txt file2.txt but that just prints out the entire second file. not sure how to fix this. Thank you.

Comment: Does the order of rows have to be maintained?

Comment: yes, or else I won't be able to get the correct message ("hello")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an awk classic:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}{print a[$1]}' file2 file1
h
e
l
l
o
```

Explained:

```
$ awk '
NR==FNR {       # processing file2
    a[$1]=$2    # hash records, first field as key, second is the value
    next
} {             # second file
    print a[$1] # output, change the record with related, stored one
}' file2 file1
```

Comment: _All right, uh, all right this is uh, this is an oldie, but uh, well, it's an oldie where I come from, uh. All right, guys, uh, listen. This is a blues riff in 'B', watch me for the changes, and try and keep up, okay.:_